# AWS Rekognition Collection

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rekognition

I have a project that recognize faces in multiple location, i want to group faces according to their location, and group locations according to their region. Is there something like a collection with sub collection in AWS rekognition?

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no sub collections in AWS Rekognition, you can implement this at your application layer.